# Allow manual reassignment of a default dictionary used in a function, while allowing keys in that dictionary to be non-permanently modified?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a function to return a dictionary of item:color, in which 'colors' has 4 default key/value pairs:

```
def set_colors(thing_colors=None)
    colors = {
            'Thing1': '#default_color',
            'Thing2': '#default_color',
            'Thing3': '#default_color',
            'Thing4': '#default_coloror'
            }

    if thing_colors is not None:        
        for thing, color in thing_colors.items():
            colors[thing] = color
    return colors
```

I have another function to plot variables and map the color dictionary to categories of those variables:

```
def plot_variables(xy, colors=None)
    if colors is None:
            colors = set_colors()
        else:
            colors = set_colors(colors)

    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(xy):
        axs[i].scatter(data[x], data[y], c=data.Thing.map(colors))
...
```

This mostly works as intended, I pass a dictionary of colors with a number of 'Things' to `plot_variables(colors={'thing':'color', etc})`, and it changes that number of things in the default 'colors' dictionary, leaving the 'Things' which were not passed to `plot_variables()` with their default color. This works for one call of `plot_variables()`, and reverts to the default colors on subsequent calls.

My issue is that I would like to be able to change the defualt dictionary, maintaining that change for all subsequent calls of `plot_variables()`. Like so:

```
# plots with normal default colors
plot_variables() 

# changes color of thing1, leaves all other things the default color
plot_variables(colors={'Thing1': 'color'}) 

# change any or all default colors 
set_colors(colors={'Thing1': 'color', 'Thing2': 'color'}) 

# plots with new default colors 
plot_variables() 

# changes color of thing1, all other things have the new default colors. 
plot_variables(colors={'Thing1': 'color')}
```

I'm almost certain the problem lies with defining the default 'colors' dictionary within the function, but can't find a fix.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you can simplify the `for` loop to just `colors.update(thing_colors)`

Answer (score 0):

Make the default colors a global variable. Return a copy of that to the caller so they don't change the defaults.

```
default_colors = {
    'Thing1': '#default_color',
    'Thing2': '#default_color',
    'Thing3': '#default_color',
    'Thing4': '#default_coloror'
}

def set_colors(thing_colors={})
    default_colors.update(thing_colors)
    return default_colors.copy()
```

Comment: Thank you for the update tip/quick reply. This doesn't allow set_colors() to set the new default color dictionary though (like in my last code block). I assumed the cause to be 'colors = set_colors()' inside plot_variables() which would reset default_colors to its original values each time plot_variables was called, but changing that doesn't fix it. I could redefine default_colors manually, but that means that I have to redefine the colors for ALL 'things'. Any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to change the defaults, just assign to the appropriate element of `default_colors`.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I apologise for my poor explanation. Your new answer means set_colors() works how I want it to but due to the following in plot_variables():
'
if colors is None:
        colors = default_colors
    else:
        colors = set_colors(colors)'

means plot_variables({'Thing1':'color'}) also changes the default color for that Thing1 on all subsequent calls of plot_variables(). If thats still unclear, I want plot_variables({'Thing1':'color'} to change Thing1's color for that plot only, and set_color({'Thing1':'color'} to change Thing1's color for all subsequent plots. Thanks :)

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either `set_colors()` changes the defaults permanently or it doesn't.

Comment: Assumed as much. Thanks again.

Comment: `plot_variables()` shouldn't call `set_colors()` if it doesn't want to change the defaults. It should just make its own copy of `default_colors` and use `update()` to merge its arguments into it.

Comment: I got it. Thanks man!